# extracting a public key from an Ed25519 private key with OpenSSL?

Tags: public-key, openssl

Ed25519 private keys can be generated by doing `openssl genpkey -algorithm ed25519 -outform PEM -out private.pem`. My question is...  using OpenSSL is there a way to get the public key from the private key?

With RSA private keys you can do `openssl rsa -in private.pem -pubout`. That gives a key that corresponds to SubjectPublicKeyInfo in RFC5280 (at least it did for me).

But how could I get a similar public key for Ed25519 keys? I guess I could generate a CSR with the private key and get it from the CSR but that seems like a lot of work. Certainly it's a lot more work then running a single command...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The formatting is identical to the RSA command, but uses the pkey command instead:

```
openssl pkey -in private.pem -pubout

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MCowBQYDK2VwAyEABhjHE6AOa33q2JGlVk9OjICRp2S6d9nUJh0Xr6PUego=
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

You can also do this to view the algorithm that was detected from the private key file, as well as the raw bytes of the keys:

```
openssl pkey -in private.pem -pubout -text

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MCowBQYDK2VwAyEABhjHE6AOa33q2JGlVk9OjICRp2S6d9nUJh0Xr6PUego=
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
ED25519 Private-Key:
priv:
    55:a9:89:ff:76:ae:c9:4f:51:dd:ee:63:80:a5:ae:
    e7:4a:e9:1d:a6:99:85:a3:09:38:04:a7:12:1c:10:
    7b:71
pub:
    06:18:c7:13:a0:0e:6b:7d:ea:d8:91:a5:56:4f:4e:
    8c:80:91:a7:64:ba:77:d9:d4:26:1d:17:af:a3:d4:
    7a:0a
```